# multiple select query with same table, what is wrong?

Tags: php, mysql

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `owv_product_option` (
  `product_option_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `product_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `option_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `option_value` text NOT NULL,
  `required` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`product_option_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=7 ;


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `owv_product_option_value` (
  `product_option_value_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `product_option_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `product_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `option_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `option_value_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `quantity` int(3) NOT NULL,
  `subtract` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `price` decimal(15,4) NOT NULL,
  `price_prefix` varchar(1) NOT NULL,
  `points` int(8) NOT NULL,
  `points_prefix` varchar(1) NOT NULL,
  `weight` decimal(15,8) NOT NULL,
  `weight_prefix` varchar(1) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`product_option_value_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=9 ;
SELECT distinct(pv.product_id)
FROM owv_product_option pv, owv_product_option_value pov
where pov.product_id = pv.product_id
and pov.option_id in (1,2)
and (pov.option_value_id in (2,6))
and (pov.option_value_id in (3))
```

I have 2 Products

1st product "Black Blouse" with

- Color:Red, Blue
- Size: Small, Medium

2nd product "Blue Jeans" with

- Color:Blue
- Size:None

I have filter which showing

- Color:
- Red
- Blue
- Black

Size

- Small
- Medium
- large

if I selected Color Blue its showing 2 products and I selected Size Small its still showing 0 products, I need show only 1 product

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! May I refer you to this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist

Comment: I want show records from same table example Size = 12 and Color = Black and Red, but one product size 12 with color Black and 2nd only size 12 only, but its showing both products, I try above queries, its showing error

Comment: So where's the check for size=12, or for color=black or for color=red? My telepathic understanding of an unknown database structure doesn't work on weekends; but it seems an excessively complex query for something that should be pretty simple if you just described the database structure for us

Comment: SELECT distinct(pv.product_id) FROM owv_product_option pv, owv_product_option_value pov where pov.product_id = pv.product_id and pov.option_id in (1,2) and (pov.option_value_id in (2,6))

Comment: 1 and 2 is color id and 2 and 6 is size id in same table, for example I have 2 products with one of color id 1 and size is 2 and 2 product with 2, so filter not showing any records

Comment: So why do you have these convoluted IN clauses with subselects? And can you please provide the basic database structures that you're using.... like I said previously, without that basic information, it requires a Masters degree in telepathic communication to understand what your database is like

Comment: CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `owv_product_option` (
  `product_option_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `product_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `option_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `option_value` text NOT NULL,
  `required` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`product_option_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=7 ;

Comment: SELECT distinct(pv.product_id) FROM owv_product_option pv, owv_product_option_value pov where pov.product_id = pv.product_id and pov.option_id in (1,2) and (pov.option_value_id in (2,6)) and (pov.option_value_id in (3)) 

I have 2 Products

1st product "Black Blouse" with 
Color:Red, Blue
Size: Small, Medium

2nd product "Blue Jeans" with 
Color:Blue
Size:None

I have filter which showing
Color:
Red
Blue
Black

Size
Small
Medium
large

if I selected Color Blue its showing 2 products and I selected Size Small its still showing 2 products, I need show only 1 product

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your query is the second `in` statement.  The table alias `pv2` is not defined in the outer context.  This is probably what you mean:

```
SELECT distinct(pv.product_id) 
  FROM owv_product_option pv, 
       owv_product_option_value pov 
 where pov.product_id = pv.product_id 
   and pov.option_value_id in (2,5) 
   and pv.option_id = '1' 
   and pv.products_id in ( SELECT distinct(pv2.product_id) 
                             FROM owv_product_option pv2, 
                                  owv_product_option_value pov2 
                            where pov2.product_id = pv2.product_id 
                              and pov2.option_value_id in (4,7) 
                              and pv2.option_id = '2'
                         ) 
   and pv.products_id in ( SELECT distinct(pv3.product_id)
                              FROM owv_product_option pv3,
                                   owv_product_option_value pov3
                             where pov3.product_id = pv3.product_id
                               and pov3.option_value_id in (8)
                               and pv3.option_id = '3'
                          )
```

I think this query can be simplified, but it is hard to say, because you give no information on the table structure or the intention of the query.  The downvotes are probably because you did not include this information in your question.

EDIT:

As I expected, the problem is a set-within-sets query.  First, your query is:

```
SELECT distinct(pv.product_id)
FROM owv_product_option pv, owv_product_option_value pov
where pov.product_id = pv.product_id
and pov.option_id in (1,2)
and (pov.option_value_id in (2,6))
and (pov.option_value_id in (3))
```

For any given row, `pov.option_value_id` cannot be be "either 2 or 6" *and* "3".  You want this version, where the logic is moved to the `having` clause:

```
SELECT pv.product_id
FROM owv_product_option pv join
     owv_product_option_value pov
     on pov.product_id = pv.product_id
group by pv.product_id
having sum(pov.option_id in (1,2) and pov.option_value_id in (2,6)) > 0 and
       sum(pov.option_id in (1,2) and pov.option_value_id in (3)) > 0;
```

That is, you need rows for each produce where the conditions are true.  There are multiple rows, so you have to group them together and look for patterns in the set.  You can't find them using a `where` clause on a single row.

Comment: I did added all above, Thank you Gordon, please check above all comments

Comment: @Sallu . . . You need to edit the question.  People who look at the question don't want to have to read all the comments to figure out what the real question is.  Just click on the "edit" button underneath it and explain better what your problem is and what you have tried.

Comment: I DID EDIT QUESTION< PLEASE CHECK NOW< THANK YOU

Comment: Got this erro #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'LIMIT 0, 30' at line 8